# How do I import a list of dtypes from a CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dtype

I am assigning dtypes after importing them from a csv file because of the nature of the data's initial formatting and currently have an array of dtypes that I assign as I go through each csv file.

Example:

```
dtypes = [{"ID": str, "Place": str, "Speed":float, "Major Street": str},
          {"ID": str, "Place": str, "Speed":float, "Roy's Boulevard": str},
          {"ID": str, "Place": str, "Speed":float, "Cassandra Park": str}]
```

I'd prefer to have this array in a different file so that I don't clutter up my code with a huge array later on. Should I have this in a separate python file that I import, or is there a way to split/strip from a csv?

An example of how each individual csv looks as follows:

https://pastebin.com/vW98iC3K

Additional code to show what I'm trying to accomplish with this dictionary:

```
  for n in tq(range(4)):
      df = pd.read_csv(r'S:\Energy\'+ meterfile[n] + '.csv', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']], skiprows=[1], usecols=dictionary[n])
              first_nan = df[df.Date_Time == 'nan nan'].first_valid_index()
              df = df[:first_nan]
              df.fillna(0)
              df = df.astype(dtypes[n])




              df.to_csv(r'S:\Energy\Database Progress\CleanedWorksheets\\' +
              meterfile[n] + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing: *"currently have an array of dtypes that I assign as I go through each csv file"* Do you mean you programmatically assign the dtypes, in code? But your code looks wrong, you only need to assign the dtype once for each column. Not for every single row and column.

Comment: If you post a snippet of your actual CSV file and code, that's better.

Comment: Right, so I import a csv and it automatically assigns the elements to an object dtype because of the way the data is initially formatted. I clean it after importing so that I can reassign the correct dtype to each element. This loops through multiple csvs with, for the most part, unique columns (except for ID, Place, and Speed in this example). I see how it looks like I'm trying to assign for every single row but what I'm doing is assigning it to the columns and then exporting that df to a csv before moving onto the next. What I'm asking is, how do I import my dtypes from a file?

Comment: **Post your actual CSV file and code**, in the question. ([SO rules require this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)). Then we can answer you.

Comment: As requested, I edited my question for clarity. Your first bullet point is essentially what I'm doing, accepting the default and changing after the fact but I want to do it in mass from a file. Again, I know how to change/assign dtypes as I'm already doing that but the csv sample I posted in the paste bin is only 1 of 94 and I would rather have my dtypes in a separate file.

Comment: In order to know each CSV file's column-name and dtypes programmatically, you'd probably have to first read in the header row of each CSV file and map it to dtypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options:

#### 1 Read the CSV in as default, fix the dtypes after

i.e don't specify dtypes, they will default to string. Then fix up the non-string columns after (you only have `'Speed': float` in your example).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(..., dtype = {'ID': 'object', 'Place': 'object', 'Speed': float}, ...)

# Then fix up any dtype after the read:
df['misread_col'] = df['misread_col'].astype(...)
```

See the [doc on `dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#dtype)

OR:

#### 2 Programmatically figure out in advance what dtype each column should be

Specify the dtype for each column at read-time: `pd.read_csv(... dtype={...} ...)`, as a dict of `'name': dtype`. This would require you to know the column names in advance (or maybe use regexes to assign dtypes based on name). And in order to do that programmatically, you'd probably have to first read in the header row of each CSV file and map it to dtypes.

And if you want to programmatically read in the header row of each CSV file and map it to dtypes:

```
import glob

for f in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    # First, read header row, to infer dtypes
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header=[0])
    #print(df.columns)
    # Here you can process df.columns, add it into a dtype_dict, whatever

    # Second, reread entire file
    df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype=...)
```

Honestly, doing 1) could be less grief than 2), it depends. Just read everything in, tweak your dtypes specifiers, run it again. If you're debugging this, just read with say `nrow=100`.